# Entity access controler not called from custom route

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I define a custom entity named "Politician", where I set the class PoliticianAccessControl as an access handler. This is working fine for the canonical url of the entity set in the following way:

```
entity.politician.canonical:
  path: '/politician/{politician}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\EntityViewController\PoliticianViewController::view'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\EntityViewController\PoliticianViewController::title'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'politician.view'
```

See the entity access requirement? Here the method PoliticianAccessControl->checkAccess() ist called, everything works just fine.

But when I try the same with another custom route the PoliticianAccessControl class gets not called and I always get an access denied message:

```
entity.politician.about_me:
  path: '/politician/{politician}/about-me'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\PoliticianFrontend\AboutMe::build'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\PoliticianFrontend\AboutMe::title'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'politician.view'
```

What do I forget?

Comment: When I have a look at the controller AboutMe::build() where I expect the parameter $politician to be an Politician entity I see that no loaded entity arrives here but just the id, which is part of the route. Why does this happen here? The {politician} parameter is written in the same way as the entity type id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the router a nudge towards what `$politician` is supposed to be for the automatic up-casting to kick in. There are two ways to do that:

1. Type-hint the variable in the controller method:

   ```
   function build(Politician $politician) {
   ```

   See [EntityResolverManager::setParametersFromReflection](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityResolverManager.php/function/EntityResolverManager%3A%3AsetParametersFromReflection/8.7.x) for details
2. Explicitly set the parameter type in the route config (which is pretty much what the first method does for you)

   ```
   options:
     parameters:
       politician:
         type: 'entity:politician'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to do a [route parameter upcasting](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/parameter-upcasting-in-routes):

```
entity.politician.about_me:
  path: '/politician/{politician}/about-me'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\PoliticianFrontend\AboutMe::build'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\pw_basic\Controller\PoliticianFrontend\AboutMe::title'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'politician.view'
  options:
    parameters:
      politician:
        type: entity:politician
```